# Append array of values to the current array in a state in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I have the state values as

```
this.state = {
    emp: [
        {id: "1", name: "A"}
        {id: "2", name: "B"}
        {id: "3", name: "B"}
    ]
}
```

How can I add an array like `var arr = {id:"4", name:"D"}` to the state `emp` without removing the current values of array. I just want to append the new array of values to the current state array. Can anyone help?

Comment: please make `var arr = [{id: "4", name: "D"}]`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In modern JavaScript you can use the spread operator:

Add a single item

```
addItem = item => {
  this.setState({
    emp: [
      ...this.state.emp,
      item 
    ]
  })
}
```

Add multiple items:

```
addItems = items => {
  this.setState({
    emp: [
      ...this.state.emp,
      ...items
    ]
  })
}
```

The [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) places all the elements in `this.state.emp` in a new array instance and `item` gets appended as the last element.

You should not mutate a component's state with other means than [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) as your rendered data will get out of sync.

Comment: Maybe you could provide some details of why this should be the way to do it. This should be the accepted answer but flesh it out a little. Why you should use `setState` and what the spread operator does.

Comment: This is not working. It appends as nested array inside `emp`

Comment: your example is a bit unclear. you are talking about an array but the code in the text shows just an object.

Comment: @lipp's answer is the correct way to append to an array in React state. Can you give an example of the input and incorrect output you're getting when using his answer?

Comment: Yes this works now. I used your example for multiple items. Thanks @lipp

Answer (score 6):

just use [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

`this.setState({ emp: this.state.emp.concat('new value') })`

The reasons why concat is better than `push`, `unshift` are

**Array.push**

> Array.prototype.push allows us to push elements to the end of an
>   array. This method does not return a new copy, rather mutates the
>   original array by adding a new element and returns the new length
>   property of the object upon which the method was called.

**Array.unshift**

> To add elements to the very beginning of an array. Just as push, unshift does not return a new copy of the modified array, rather the new length of the array

Both the ways changes the mutation state of an `array`. A mutation term is meant to be unchanged because it is our original source.

**array.concat**

The **concat()** method is used to merge two or more arrays. This method does not change the existing arrays, but instead returns a new array.

However, You [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) too, that creates a deep copy of object assigned to it.

```
let emp = Object.assign([],this.state.emp); //type of an array
```

result 
[image]

Comment: I was literally in the middle of typing a comment about mutating with `push()` when you updated it haha :P

Comment: @Jayce444, Just realized what could go wrong literally :D

Answer (score 4):

You need to update if using functional setState(since you are updating state based on prevState) and spread syntax like

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
    emp: [
        ...prevState.emp, 
        {id:"4",name:"c"}
    ]
}))
```

Comment: This appends as a nested array to the array value. Not the required result

Answer (score 0):

If using a functional component, voila a simple example:

```
const [hiddenDivs, setHiddenDivs] = useState([1, 2, 3, 4]);

const handleCatDivTitleClick = (divNum: number) => {
   if (hiddenDivs.includes(divNum)) {
      setHiddenDivs(hiddenDivs.filter((d) => d !== divNum));  //REMOVE FROM ARRAY
   } else {
      setHiddenDivs([...hiddenDivs, divNum]);  //ADD TO ARRAY
   }
};

<div class={`${style.catDiv} ${hiddenDivs.includes(1) ? style.catDivHide : ''}`}>
   <div class={style.catTitle} onClick={() => handleCatDivTitleClick(1)}>
      Imagine a list of categories like this. All begin "hidden" (shrunk-up).
   </div>
</div>
<div class={`${style.catDiv} ${hiddenDivs.includes(2) ? style.catDivHide : ''}`}>
   <div class={style.catTitle} onClick={() => handleCatDivTitleClick(2)}>
       You want to shrink/expand category based on clicking title.
   </div>
</div>
<div class={`${style.catDiv} ${hiddenDivs.includes(3) ? style.catDivHide : ''}`}>
   <div class={style.catTitle} onClick={() => handleCatDivTitleClick(3)}>
      Basically, a home-rolled accordian-type display.
   </div>
</div>
```